# submitting select2 form with jquery upon single select dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a single select dropdown. When a user makes a selection, I want the form to submited with jquery.

my jquery code is as follows:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){ 
  function matchStart(params, data) {
      params.term = params.term || '';
      if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
          return data;
      }
      return false;
  }

  $("select#user_country").select2({
    matcher: function(params, data) {
        return matchStart(params, data);
    },
    placeholder: "Select a country",
  })

  $("select#user_country").on('select2:select', function (event) {
     return ('form#selectcountry').submit();
  });

});
```

Rails view:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :get, id: 'selectcountry' do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag "country", options_from_collection_for_select(ISO3166::Country.countries.sort_by(&:name), 'un_locode', 'name'), :include_blank => true %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => "nil", :id => "submit-me" %>
<% end %>
```

[Link here to 'select2:select' documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#how-can-i-attach-listeners-for-these-events)

```
$('select').on('select2:select', function (evt) {
  // Do something
});
```

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that the event listener works, i have tested it with an alert message, it is just not submitting the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('select#country').on('select2:select', function () {
  $('input#submit-me').trigger('click');
});
```

Couldn't get the form to submit so just did it like this.